# Exponentiation of a power series

Tags: proof-writing, power-series, exponentiation

How may I derive the following identity?

$$ \Big( \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n \Big)^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \tilde{c}_n x^{n-1} $$

$$ \text{where } \ \tilde{c}_n = \sum_{\substack{n_1 \dots n_k \\ n_1+ \cdots+n_k +1 = n}} c_{n_1} \dots c_{n_k} \qquad$$

I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

Reference: Page 4 of [this document](https://wiki.physik.uni-muenchen.de/TMP/images/7/74/Classical_fields.pdf).

Comment: you meant $$ \tilde{c}^{(k)}_n = \sum_{\substack{n_1, \dots, n_k \\ n_1+ \cdots+n_k = n}} c_{n_1} \dots c_{n_k} = \sum_{m=0}^n \tilde{c}_m^{(k-1)}c_{n-m}$$ the suggestion is to look at the case $k=2$ then $k=3$

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. That's what's written in the text I am reading. I will add the reference to my question.

Comment: **You meant** $$\Big( \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n \Big)^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \tilde{c}_n x^{n}$$

Comment: @user1952009 He meant what he meant.

Comment: @Andreas what ? no the OP meant what I and you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort for powers of $x$:
$$
\Big( \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n \Big)^k = \\
\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty c_{n_1} x^{n_1} \sum_{n_2=0}^\infty c_{n_2} x^{n_2} \cdots \sum_{n_k=0}^\infty c_{n_k} x^{n_k} \\
= \sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \sum_{n_2=0}^\infty  \cdots \sum_{n_k=0}^\infty c_{n_1} c_{n_2} \cdots  c_{n_k} x^{n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + {n_k} }\\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \tilde{c}_n x^{n}$$

where the $\tilde{c}_n$ are sums over all products $c_{n_1} c_{n_2} \cdots  c_{n_k}$ where ${n_1} + {n_2} + \cdots {n_k}$ matches the power $n$.

Now, for your slightly different notation, you can shift $n$ by $1$ in the sum ${n_1} + {n_2} + \cdots {n_k}$ and in the power of $x$. Then you write the power $x^{n-1}$ and correspondingly you must match ${n_1} + {n_2} + \cdots {n_k} = n-1$ or ${n_1} + {n_2} + \cdots {n_k} +1 = n$.

Comment: Also this is allowed only at the $x$ where it converges absolutely

Comment: You forgot an equality in front of your last term. Anyway, I didn't quite get the argument about shifting $n$ by 1. Could you maybe comment a little more on this?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, absolute convergence is necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Rahman come on I explained this in the comments.

Comment: I put more explanation in the main text.